# Issue with the database on ecery run

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a project recently did it on .NET Framework 3.5 but now using it in VS 2013.I look on more threads at SO but they didn't satisfied.I added to it a database after opening it in VS 2013.Added and connected database successfuly but when i run it says,

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Here is my connection:

```
public bool ConnectDB()
    {

       con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Db_doc_Clinic;Integrated Security=true";
        //con.ConnectionString=
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the exception text and the text of all of the nested inner exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

For proper database connectionstring , i would suggest you to navigate through `View->Server Explorer -> Database Connections` and from there connect to your database. Now right click on that the db in Server Explorer and opt properties. There you will see `ConnectionString` property, copy and paste it here.

```
private SqlConnection con ;
public bool ConnectDB()
{
  con= new SqlConnection();
  con.ConnectionString= your_copied_string;
  if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)//always true
  {
     con.Open();
     return true;

  }
}
```